# Excel - Wrong result when finding simple quartile exercise

Tags: excel

I have the following values places in row 1 (cell `A1` to cell `L1`):

`1  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   7   7   8   10`

I can find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th quartiles using:

```
=QUARTILE(A1:L1,1)
=QUARTILE(A1:L1,2)
=QUARTILE(A1:L1,3)
=QUARTILE(A1:L1,4)
```

Based on my calculation by hand and some online calculator, the values, respectively, should be `2.5`, `5.5`, `7` and `10`. However, Excel gives `2.75` for 1st quartile. I should mention that the Excel sheet used is the default sheet without changing the formatting of any cell. Why is that?

Comment: [Possibly helpful](https://superuser.com/questions/343339/excel-quartile-function-doesnt-work).

Comment: There are different methods to calculate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile  The online calculators probably use method 1 or method 4 while Excel uses method 2.